# How to nest an If statement in an if statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a cell that I want to calculate this if statement `=IF(E7>D7,E7-D7,D7-E7)` but only if the Cell G7 is yes.

I wrote this formula `=IF(G7=yes,(IF(E7>D7,E7-D7,D7-E7)),"n/a")` but it doesn't work, how would I fix it?

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: i get the #Name? error

Comment: @shelby, you are getting `#Name` error because in `IF(G7=yes` the `yes` is without quotes and it must be like `"Yes"` or `"yes"`. Since it's without quotes, Excel considers it as **Reserve word (Function/Command)** and Excel does't have any !!

Answer (score 4):

You could also get the absolute value of the difference:

```
=IF(G7="yes",ABS(E7-D7), "n/a")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add extra brackets for the nested IF statement. Try this:

```
=IF(G7="yes",IF(E7>D7,E7-D7,D7-E7), "n/a")
```

Comment: it removed the Name error, but even with Yes in G7, it still returns n/a

Comment: Odd. It's should be working https://snag.gy/xsBfD4.jpg. Start a new sheet and try it again. The cell format might be irregular.

Comment: That worked, I had the yes and no options as a drop down menu, so i think that might have been the issue, once i got rid of that it woked..